# 64 bit win 7, 2.3 GHz Processor, 3 GB ram, 300 Gig Hard drive. CPU is running at 100 percent with no visible apps running in Win Task Manager.

Tags: windows-7

I am using 64 bit win 7, 2.3 GHz Processor, 3 GB ram, with a 300 Gig Hard drive. CPU is running at 100 percent with no visible apps running in Win Task Manager. This is a second hand computer and I don't have the win 7 software. What would be the most inexpensive way to wipe out and reinstall windows 7?

Comment: Do you have a product key for Windows 7? If it is a desktop then look on the sides for a sticker. If it a laptop then look on the bottom.

Comment: Yes I do have the product key. I'm currently trying to see if their "Restore" function will work, but I would rather wipe it clean and do a fresh install.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/78761/where-can-i-download-windows-7-legally-from-microsoft for links to download a Windows 7 ISO from Microsoft. You can then burn it to DVD and use it to reinstall the OS using your product key.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, whenever I turned on the pc, a service used 100% CPU, I discovered it was something related to Windows Update. I disabled the Windows Update and then restarted the PC that the problem did not happen anymore. Today I enable Win Update once a week just to download and install the necessary updates, then I turn again to the problem does not return.

Comment: Thanks. I did try and turned off win update. It didn't work. Still running at 100% cpu.